# MOS Amplifier Circuit - Lower 3dB Frequency Calculation

Tags: amplifier, analog, cutoff-frequency

[image]

[image]

I am confused with the above problem as the output node is not specified. If the output node is drain, it will be common source and if output is source, then it will be common drain.

My question is that is it necessary to specify the output node to calculate lower cutoff frequency or the solution is ok ?

Comment: But if you add this information about the output node. Will it change anything in the way you calculate the frequency?

Comment: What my instructor taught was to calculate Vo/Vs from small signal model which will come of the form s/s+a and a will give me the lower cutoff frequency.

Comment: I can't calculate Vo/Vs until I know the output node

Comment: Because we only have one capacitor. To find the FL all you need to do is to find the "equivalent resistance" seen by the capacitor. And this is what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to know the output node (drain). It makes no sense to have it at the source because there is no low-frequency cut-off point because the source voltage largely follows the gate voltage.

The low frequency cut-off (3 dB point) with respect to the drain as output is when XCs = Rs. At this point the gain reduces down to a level dictated by Rd/Rs and the gain remains at this level down to DC.

Comment: What my instructor taught was to calculate Vo/Vs from small signal model which will come of the form s/s+a and a will give me the lower cutoff frequency. This method is ok ? I can't understand your way of calculating fL.

Comment: At X_Cs = Rs we have a zero not a pole.